# Bizarre touchscreen behavior

Tags: windows-10, usb, touchscreen

I have a Waveshare 10.1 Inch hdmi touchscreen, connected to a Windows 10 machine.

The screen registers touch fine (all 10 as advertised), it will scroll, but it won't register "clicks". Or better, it does, but won't act on them. The small "circle" will appear, if I hold it will start a rightclick, but freeze on the square (no rightclick menu).

Oddly enough, it will work perfectly in Chrome, and apps like Spotify for example. Not so in others.
Also very weird, on the on screen windows keyboard, no key works, but backspace, space and slash do work fine. But if I multitouch the keyboard, some strokes will register.

When trying for example to close chrome, or minimize, it will show the X or _ as in a hover state, without acting on it.

I have disabled, re-enabled, update drivers automatically etc, nothing. Vendor offers no firmware or driver upgrade.

This is definitely the weirdest issue I have ever come across. Because of the nature of the behavior, I'm very inclined in thinking its a software issue, specifically a Windows 10 issue. I bet it would work fine on a Windows 7 machine for example, but I don't have one to test.

Comment: Have you tried running Windows 10 in tablet mode? I believe it handles touch input a little different then.

Comment: @cascer1 I have, it makes absolutely no difference. Windows keeps ignoring the "taps", chrome keeps reading them fine.